# How to make a Controller Singleton in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I'm making an airlines web app. Right now I'm coding de process of reserving a flight, for that purpose I have multiple views such as `reserve.blade.php`, `chooseFlights.blade.php`, `passengersInfo.blade.php`, etc. 
All those views use the same `ReserveController` class. The routes are specified in the `web.php` file like so:

```
Route::get('/reserve', 'ReserveController@searchFlights');
Route::get('/reserve/choose_flights', 'ReserveController@chooseFlights');
Route::post('/reserve/storeFlightsIds', 'ReserveController@storeFlightsIds');
Route::get('/reserve/passengers_info', 'ReserveController@retrievePassengersInfo');
```

Where those methods return the respective views with the needed data to be displayed.

The workflow of reserving is `/reserve` (returns the view `reserve.blade.php`) that view makes a get request to -> `/reserve/choose_flights` (returns the view `chooseFlights.blade.php`) that view makes a post request to -> `/reserve/storeFlightsIds` (returns the view `passengersInfo.blade.php`).

In `reserve.blade.php` info like the origin and destiny of the desired flight, the dates and number of passengers is sent to the controller. The problem is the number of passengers is required steps further in the `passengersInfo.blade.php` for  the view to know how many forms has to display to retrieve the info of all the passengers.

I would like to use the same instance of the `ReserveController` whenever a request involving it is accessed so that way I can store the needed data in properties and share the same data corresponding to the current reserve process across all those views.

Is it possible?

Comment: store the info in session or database or build your app in javascript where you keep a shared state until the final submit.

Comment: What exactly keeps you from doing it? Where's the connection to a "singleton"? How does using such a "Controller Singleton" help you to store the data between multiple requests?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use the same instance of the ReserveController whenever a request involving it is accessed so that way I can store the needed data in properties and share the same data corresponding to the current reserve process across all those views.
>
> Is it possible?

Yes its possible, you register a singleton instance in your app's service container

```
$this->app->singleton('MySingleton', function ($app) {
     return new SomeSharedClass(...);
});
```

and then you store the shared state inside that class. And  inject it in your controller.

```
class ReserveController extends Controller 
{
     private $singleton;

     function __construct(MySingleton $singleton) {
         $this->singleton = $singleton;
     }

     ...
}
```

Warning!! This is not recommended. Remember if 2 different users will call the same controller method, they will also share the singleton instances.
**shared state is evil!**

Read more about shared states here.
http://henrikeichenhardt.blogspot.com/2013/06/why-shared-mutable-state-is-root-of-all.html

Comment: What do you mean by "2 different users"? How could it be possible that two completely seperated requests share a singleton instance?

Comment: Yes thats correct. A singleton is a class that has only one instance.

Comment: @NicoHaase with things like Laravel Octane, it is possible that the separate requests would share the same singleton instance. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane#managing-memory-leaks